# Find Surface area by revolving about initial line.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

> Question: Sketch the graph and find the points on the cardioid $r = a(1 +\cos\theta )$ at which tangent lines are horizontal. Also, find its surface area by revolving about initial line.

**Answer**:
The initial line is the $x$-axis

$$S = 2\pi \int_0^\pi y ds,$$

$ds = \sqrt{r^2+{r'}^2} dθ = \sqrt{a^2(1+\cosθ)^2 + (-a\sinθ)^2}dθ = a\sqrt{2(1+\cosθ)}dθ$

$$S = 2\pi a^2\int_0^\pi (1+\cos\theta)\sqrt{2(1+\cos\theta)}  d\theta$$

let $u = 1+\cos\theta$, $du = -\sin\theta$,

when $\theta= 0, u = 2$

I have done this so far. Now I am not understanding what to do.

Comment: Please use Mathjax to format your equations. It's very hard to read your question

Comment: I have fixed some of your mathjax. Some of them I can't really understand what that is, so I left it. You may click "edit" to edit your question and also see how mathjax is used.

Answer (score 1):

Please note $y = r \sin \theta$ so your integral should be

$S = \displaystyle 2\pi a^2 \int_0^\pi (1+\cos\theta) \sin \theta \sqrt{2(1+\cos\theta)} \  d\theta$

Now substitute,  $t = 1+\cos\theta, dt = - \sin \theta \ d\theta$. So,

$S = \displaystyle 2 \sqrt2\pi a^2 \int_0^2 t^{3/2} dt  = \frac{32 \pi a^2}{5}$

Comment: Any reaction? Did it help? Any questions?